How to remove paint from the window frame?
There is paint on the window frame from a previous owner not taping the window off before painting. It is on the window frame and some is on the caulking of the window frame as well. See picture below of the problem. I am not sure if it's plastic or metal, so I have been wary of trying something like a paint thinner that would eat away at the plastic. I have tried using a hard plastic scraper with no luck. I am worried about using a razor blade because I don't want to scrape the paint on the window frame off.
Would love a surefire way of removing this so I can tape it off properly and paint the edge.


It looks more like caulking on trim, not on a window frame.  In most cases it is cleaned and painted over.   Is this the exterior of the house?

I'm just not getting the problem here.  Are you talking about the greenish strip of color?  Why not simply paint over it?

I'm also not sure what you're asking about. The green stripe is on a jamb (opening trim), not a window frame. Please try to get a focused image and mark it up for clarity.

This is on the interior. My terminology might be wrong. I don't know what to call this part of the window. It's the nonmoving part of the window and it seems like it's made of plastic or metal. There is green paint on the caulking and this white piece on the window. The green on the caulking I can paint over. I just need a way to clean the green paint off the window part up to the caulking so I can tape that part off and paint.
I don't want to just paint over it because the paint should not be there in the first place .
